# NServiceBus - is SLR enabled by default?

Tags: nservicebus

I've read this on NServiceBus website about Second-Level Retries (SLR). What I didn't understand from the article is weather SLR is enabled by default or just if I put it's code setting in the .config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second level retries are enabled by default.  You only need to add them to the config if you want to change default behavior.